# Django And Aframe - OBJ, MTL files not being rendered in the AFrame scene

Tags: django, aframe

I am building an application wherein the django and Aframe frameworks are being used. The idea is to a load an apple object (.obj and .mtl file included) when I traverse to a new page. The problem is that I Django gives me the following warning : **Not Found: /education/Apple.mtl.** 
I have placed the object in the same folder as that of the html page I want to load. The problem is that although the enitre html file is running properly, the obj files does not seem to load when I run them in Django but they normally run when Just ran through running on the web browser. So the main question is:
Does Django support rendering of obj files and if they do then what exactly is the problem? Please help. Thanks in advance.
Here is a screenshot and the code.

[The file directory structure and the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMMhc.png)

```html
  <html>
    <head>
     <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a-scene>
    
      <a-entity obj-model="obj: apple.obj; mtl: apple.mtl; scale: 0.1 0.1 0.1; position: 0 5 -2" ></a-entity>
      <a-entity position="0 70 150">
     <a-camera></a-camera>
      <a-entity>
    
    </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a 404 error for the mtl. The file is not available on that route. Check if the file is served on a different URL. It doesn’t seem a problem specific to A-Frame but to the Django server configuration.

Comment: What am I supposed to check in the django server configurations sir? I tried running the html file outside Django by placing the file and the .obj and .mtl files and it runs fluently. I figured the same that Django is creating some havoc..so what should I check and what should I change? ..because once again I have just placed the obj file and mtl file in the same directory as that of the html file inside the django project and its still not working.

Comment: I've never used Django so I can't help. An mtl file in the same directory as the HTML template does not guarantee that it will be served from the same route or served at all by Django. [These docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) could be a good starting point.

Comment: That was it. It worked for me. Thank you so much sir!